# Get errors for view from MessageManger

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to switch from manual validation to using the Message Manager.

I registered the view in the manager

`oMessageManager.registerObject(this.getView(), true);`

I added constraints to my controls

```
<Input                                               
    value="{
        path: 'viewModel>Value',
        type:'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Decimal', 
        formatOptions: {minFractionDigits:0, maxFractionDigits:2, decimalSeparator:',', groupingSeparator: ''},
        constraints: {precision: 13, scale: 2}
    }"
    description="{parts: [{path : 'viewModel>Currency'}, {path: 'viewModel>Unit'}], formatter: '.formatter.formatMeasure' }"
    fieldGroupIds="required-value"
    textAlign="Right"                                                    >
</Input>
```

and yes it works, the control gets is state update if constraints are violated.

But now if the user were to click the submit button, is there a good way to check if the current view contains errors?

ATM I'm using the fieldGroupsIds, loop over them to get the errorStateValue for each control and check if it is None. But I suppose there must be a better way.

Comment: I'm very curious because I'm using fieldGroupsIsd too and I've always wondered if there is a better way

Comment: Well in the MessageModel.OData.Messanges I see the errors, but they are application wide (not just for the current view) and no good way of filgering them (except maybe a regex with the viewname)

Comment: Same situation here

Comment: On a related note, when binding a model.odata.type.Decimal, the initial value is "" but formattedValue is "0", is there a way to prevent the 0?

Comment: I think you should look into the emptyString property of the FormatOptions but maybe it's better if you open a new question ;-)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for, found it like 3 minutes after asking here, but thanks a lot :)

Comment: I asked for this, as far I know this is still not solved https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1898